# How to start a process immediately after the user upload new file?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

We have a PHP project in which the user uploads a file and the software starts a process of encrypting that file.

This process takes approx 5-7 minutes in encrypting.

But when the encrypting process is going on, in between another user uploads the file. Then our process stops and starts the process again.

To overcome this we made a process table also in which the file path of the new file is stored in FIFO manner, but still as new file is added, the process starts again.

**What should be done that the process does not stops and the file should wait for its turn?**

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_process";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$countforh = mysqli_num_rows($result);
for($h = 1; $h<=$countforh; $h++)
{
 $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_process WHERE (sr_no = '".$h."' AND com_status = '0')";
//Con_status = 0 is for the file which is not encrypted.
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if (is_null($row['pfile_path']))
{
continue; //if Con_status = 1
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_process WHERE (sr_no = '".$h."' AND com_status = '0')"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
$_SESSION['filepath'] = $row['pfile_path'];
$_SESSION['upload_tbl_sr'] = $row['upload_sr_no'];
}
```

now we start encryption process.

Comment: for such purposes there are lot's of message queue or worker services. check this out: http://gearman.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a session or a serialized file to mark or upload the file.

Once PHP imports the file into the system, you can start recording the file or session

```
//File serialized, to First file
if($_FILES['file']['error'] != 0){    //Checks for error while importing file
    if (!file_exists($tmpF)) {
        $count = 1;
        $queue[] = ['id'=>$count,'nameFile'=>$_FILES['file']['name'],'status'=>0];
        $tmpF = sys_get_temp_dir().'/reportUpload.txt';
        $tmp = fopen($tmpF,'w');
        fwrite($tmp, serialize($queue));
        fclose($tmp);
    }else{
        //For the second file on.
        $tmpF = sys_get_temp_dir().'/reportUpload.txt';
        $file = fopen($tmpF,'r');
        $queue = unserialize(fgets($file));
        fclose($file);
        $last = count($queue);
        $count = $queue[$last]['id']+1;
        $queue[] = ['id'=>$count,'nameFile'=>$_FILES['file']['name'],'status'=>0];
        $tmp = fopen($tmpF,'w');
        fwrite($tmp, serialize($queue));
        fclose($tmp);
    }
}


//Starting Encryption
$tmpU = sys_get_temp_dir().'/reportUploadExecution.txt';
if(!file_exists($tmpU)){
    $tmpF = sys_get_temp_dir().'/reportUpload.txt';
    $file = fopen($tmpF,'r');
    $queue = unserialize(fgets($file));
    $line = 0;
    while(!feof($queue)){

       if($queue[$line]['status']==FALSE){
           //Starting Encryption
           $tmpU = sys_get_temp_dir().'/reportUploadExecution.txt';
           $execution = ['id'=>$line,'nameFile'=>$queue[$line]['nameFile']]
           $tmp1 = fopen($tmpU,'w');
           fwrite($tmp1, serialize($execution));
           fclose($tmp1);


           // Your code here


           // If encryption ended successfully set line "Status" = 1
           unlink($tmpU);
           $line++;
       }

    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

It's just an idea, if you can post part of the code, it will help you better.

Comment: Do you have a part of the PHP interaction with the start of the upload, before the encryption?

Comment: yes, we have two PHP page, in the first we upload file and store in the database and after that we call our second PHP page as: $command = "nohup /usr/bin/php backend.php ".escapeshellarg($arg)." ".escapeshellarg($arg1)."  > /dev/null 2>&1 &";
$status = shell_exec($command); in this second page the process of encryption starts.

Comment: we are doing the same way, instead of queue we are using table process in which we are adding file names of the files uploaded/added. after that we are running for loop in which it would check status of all the files whether they are encrypted or not and encryption starts which takes around 5-10 minutes. The problem is if the user uploads 4 or 5 files one-by-one, the process of for loop starts with every upload, rather it should wait for the process to be complete of the previously uploaded file.